# Migration to Google Identity Services(GIS) and Sign In using REST

Tags: android, google-oauth

I have an Android project with "Google Sign In" button.
In most of the cases, I use native Sign In SDK **BUT** cover as well the case when device has no preinstalled GooglePlayServices.
For the case, I prepare REST request and redirect it to browser.

According to [Migrate to Google Identity Services](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis#authorization_code_flow_examples) documentation, there is the ***old "redirect" way*** using REST where we have to prepare request link and make GET request.

**BUT** the new way have no REST option. There just HTML pages.

**QUESTIONS:**
do we have the option to Sign In with Google Identity Services using REST request?
Maybe someone has an idea of how to cover the case smoothly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [oauth-2.0-endpoints](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow#oauth-2.0-endpoints) with `email` and `profile` scopes and follow [branding guidelines](https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines), or assuming that you also have a website, use an Android webview with [One Tap](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/features). The latter is preferable, but on the chance you only release your app on Android the endpoint approach may help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
I'm already using "accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth". And seems like in migrating documentation it's "old way" OR I can't recognize difference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but here is the solution I used

"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth/oauthchooseaccount" as URL and default banch of parameters +   "flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow".

It's the way that Orange Flex carriers use in their native app.
If I will receive another warning from google I will update the answer.